# WPF controls not working with 3 or more monitors

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multiple-monitors

I have a .NET 4.0 WPF window based app that functions normally on a machine with one or two monitors.  However, when running the app on various windows 7 machines that have a multiple monitor configuration (3 or more) and dragging the app window to certain monitors, drop down and menu based controls will not work.

On the trouble monitors none of the drop down menus, context menus or comboboxes will open.  Also the combo box will flicker and then the text will disappear. The window is not maximized, just made big enough to fit on that monitor.  When the window is dragged back to the other monitors, this problem will no longer happen.

The controls are styled, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

This just in: I have tried an example app that i got on the MSDN website and the same thing happens, so this must not be caused by my code.  Possibly an inherent .NET issue or a driver issue?

This problem doesn't happen for other applications (non .NET).

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: There's a known issue with popups not appearing on Win XP, but haven't heard of this on Win 7. Have you tried the simplest possible, stock standard WPF app? Have you tried restarting the machine?

Comment: Is this a large application? Are you sure you haven't hit the 10 000 windows handle limit? If this is large application, watch it in task manager, enable all columns and look for suspicously round numbers (like 10 000).

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your responses.  I have tried an example WPF application that I got from the MSDN website, which is just a basic sample app demonstrating how to use templates.  The same thing happens with this app.

Comment: @alexp Do all of these machines have the same hardware configurations? Same video cards and drivers?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the "problem monitors" to the left of or above the primary monitor?

Comment: Have you tried running a basic application without hardware acceleration; you can do this doing `RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;` in your application start-up.

Comment: we ended up just forgetting about this issue for now.  it turned out to be something specific to the nvidia video cards we use here.